Disable android dialog for PWA updates
I have developed a custom PWA, which is hosted on a server in my local network. For a few months now, every now and then a dialog pops up on the home screen of my Android 14 device with the following message:

Update this app with an update from Google Play Store? It normally receives updates from Chrome. If you use an update from another source, you may receive future updates from any source on your smartphone. The functionality of the app may change

(This is a translation from the German dialog)
How can I disable this dialog?
